# MutliGet or multiple Get operations when paging

Tags: cassandra

I have a wide column family used as a 'timeline' index, where column names are timestamps. In order to prevent hotspots, I shard the CF by month so that each month has its own row in the CF.

I query the CF for a slice range between two dates and limit the number of columns returned based on the page's records per page, say to 10.

The problem is that if my date range spans several months, I get 10 columns returned from each row, even if there is 10 matching columns in the first row - thus satisfying my paging requirement.

I can see the logic in this, but it strikes me as a real inefficiency if I have to retrieve redundant records from potentially multiple nodes when I only need the first 10 matching columns regardless of how many rows they span.

So my question is, am I better off to do a single Get operation on the first row and then do another Get operation on the second row if my first call doesnt return 10 records and continue until I have the required no. of records (or hit the row limit), or just accept the redundancy and dump the unneeded records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sample your queries and record how many rows you needed to fetch for each one in order to get your 10 results and build a histogram of those numbers.  Then, based on the histogram, figure out how many rows you would need to fetch at once in order to complete, say, 90% of your lookups with only a single query to Cassandra.  That's a good start, at least.

If you almost always need to fetch more than one row, consider splitting your timeline by larger chunks than a month.  Or, if you want to take a more flexible approach, use different bucket sizes based on the traffic for each individual timeline: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-time-series-with-cassandra (see the "Variable Time Bucket Sizes" section).

Comment: A histogram seems like a worthy exercise. I just want to thank you for posting that link - it was a very interesting read. I wasn't aware of the Reversed Comparator, so +1 for that :)